# Scroll iframe parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, parent, jquery-events

How to get

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  // window scroll
});
```

in the parent window...

I thought something like `window.parent.$(window)` or `$(window, document.parent)` or etc, but this not working

I have an application in Google open social iframe and I want to get `scroll()` of main window.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(window.parent.window).scroll();` or just `$(window.parent).scroll();`

Comment: Not going to work anyway, "Result" and the parent are on different domains - interaction with the parent (and vice-versa) are extremely limited when the domains are not the same.